# jquery active (centered) slide with zoom effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions, bxslider

I'm using bxslider and I want to make current slide as a zoom effect.

sample image url : https://i.stack.imgur.com/gg5dH.jpg

Bxslider sample example: http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-demystified#example4

I have looked at a few zoom plugins, but none of them have this specific effect.

Can anyone help me with this?

Example :

(prev) image1 **image2** image3 (Next)

When I click the next. it will show like this

(prev) image2 **image3** image4 (Next)

**image3** is the currently activated so **image3** will show with zoomed effect.

Comment: And which behaviour regarding elements (prev/current/next) zoom are you expecting while slider is sliding??? This is really too broad question

Comment: Well show us your code, your effort, and maybe we will put some effort in helping you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following styling should work. Add a class "active" to the active image div. Also understand that these styling are added by JavaScript, so you would have to either modify it in the code, or mark the following styling as `!important`.

```
.bx-viewport {
height: 170px;
padding-top: 10px;
}

.slide {
margin-right: 5px;
}

.slide.active {
width: 360px;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-top: -10px;
}

.slide.active img {
width: 360px;
}
```

Hope this helps.